# OrientDB Time Span Search Query

Tags: sql, select, orientdb

In [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com/) I have setup a time series using this [use case](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Time-series-use-case.html). However, instead of appending my Vertex as an embedded list to the respective hour I have opted to just create an edge from the hour to the time dependent Vertex.

For arguments sake lets say that each hour has up to 60 time `Vertex` each identified by a timestamp. This means I can perform the following query to obtain a specific desired Vertex:

```
SELECT FROM ( SELECT expand( month[5].day[12].hour[0].out() ) FROM Year WHERE year = 2015) WHERE timestamp = 1434146922
```

I can see from the use case that I can use `UNION` to get several specified time branches in one go.

```
SELECT expand( records ) FROM (
  SELECT union( month[3].day[20].hour[10].out(), month[3].day[20].hour[11].out() ) AS records
  FROM Year WHERE year = 2015
)
```

This works fine if you only have a small number of branches but it doesn't work very well if you want to get all the records for a given time span. Say you wanted to get all the records between;

```
month[3].day[20].hour[11] -> month[3].day[29].hour[23]
```

I could iterate through the timespan and create a huge union query but at some point I guess the query would be too long and my guess is that it wouldn't be very efficient. I could also completely bypass the time branches and query the Vectors directly based on the timestamp.

```
SELECT FROM Sector WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1406588622 AND 1406588624
```

The problem being that you loose all efficiencies gained by the time branches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By experimenting and reading a bit about data types in orientdb, I found that :

The squared brackets allow to :

- filtering by one index, example out()[0]
- filtering by multiple indexes, example out()[0,2,4]
- filtering by ranges, example out()[0-9]

**OPTION 1 (UPDATE) :**

Using a union to join on multiple time is the only option if you don't want to create all indexes and if your range is small. [Here is a query exemple using union in the documentation.](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Time-series-use-case.html#join-multiple-hours)

**OPTION 2 :**

If you always have all the indexes created for your time and if you filter on wide ranges, you should filter by ranges. This is more performant then option 1 for the cost of having to create all indexes on which you want to filter on. [Official documentation about field part.](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Document-Field-Part.html)

This is how the query would look like :

```
select 
    *
from 
(
    select 
        expand(hour[0-23].out()) 
    from 
       (select 
            expand(month[3].day[20-29]) 
       from 
            Year 
       where 
            year = 2015)
)
where timestamp > 1406588622
```

I would highly recommend reading [this](http://orientdb.com/orientdb-improved-sql-filtering/).