# orientDB - graph - updated nodes based on index lookup

Tags: sql, graph, clojure, orientdb, nosql

I have a graph structure with a root node, several container nodes (I'll call them lvl1) each containing hundreds of thousands of content nodes (lvl2). The content nodes may be linked with arbitrary numbers of other content nodes. Lvl1 nodes will never link to each other and link to their lvl2 nodes exactly once. When the graph gets constructed, links between lvl2 nodes may appear multiple times, in that case I need to keep count of the links (increment a `depth` property on the appropriate edge). Also the order of construction will be quite random.

I'm looking for an efficient way to manage that graph structure with orientDB. Building it up is eays, the problem is updating lvl2 nodes (adding more links) and links between them.

One way to select could be a standard SQL-query, something like `SELECT FROM lvl2nodes WHERE id = 114` - but this would query the whole dataset and be very slow, as far as I can see (I didn't test that yet).

So my idea was to use index lookups. I created automatic indexing `CREATE INDEX lvl2node.id UNIQUE` and tried to query that: `SELECT FROM INDEX:lvl2node.id WHERE key = 114`, which gives me a tuple `({:key 114, :rid #<ODocument lvl2node#8:1{id:114,in:[2],out:[1]} v1>})`.

Now, how can I

a) use that information to select a node and update its properties and

b) find the edge between 2 such vertices to perform an update similarly

Or is there a better method to update a graphs' vertices, exploiting the graph structure? A lvl1 node's will still contain very many links that would need to be traversed without the hash-map's approach.

I'm using Clojure's clj-orient API to access orientDB.

Comment: what do you mean when you say increment a depth property on the appropriate edge ? What appropriate edge the one from lvl1 to lvl2 ?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I mean edges connecting lvl2 nodes, as lvl1->lvl2 links are assured to be unique (I think of them as "this lvl2 exists in lvl1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like stated in the [orientdb wiki](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Time-series-use-case.html) :

```
[...] "When you've millions of records indexes show their limitation 
because the cost to find the records is O(logN). This is also the main 
reason why Relational DBMS are so slow with huge database.

So when you've millions of record the best way to scale up linearly 
is  avoid using indexes at all or as much as you can. But how to  
retrieve records in short time without indexes? Should OrientDB scan 
the entire database at every query? No. You should use the Graph 
properties of OrientDB."
```

I would personnaly use linkmaps for the tree like they did with the time series use case.

It would look like something like this :

```
create class lvl1
create class lvl2
create class lvl3

create property lvl1.id integer
create property lvl1.lvl2 linkmap lvl2
create property lvl2.lvl3 linkmap lvl3
```

The keys in the linkmap would be the next level node id. To get the depth, you would use the length property of the next level linkmap property.

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion, thanks. Could you so kind as to show me an example of efficient adressing and updating a lvl2 node's value (or point me to the use case you quoted?

Comment: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Time-series-use-case.html You have a couple of query exemples in there

Comment: an answer by me on how to do powerful range queries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186297/orientdb-time-span-search-query/31199107#31199107

Comment: Thanks once more - I will work through this tomorrow (it's quality time now ;-) )

Comment: This works quite well for my smaller testcases. I'm curious how this will scale on my huge databases, but the firts benchmarks are looking good.

Comment: Ok awesome, tell me how it goes in the comment. I'm glad I have helped you